# How to get all fields through method service.files().get(id).execute() which returns google drive File in Google Drive V3 in java?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

While getting all fields for files is possible for list of files by using the method service.files().list().setFields("files"), setFields() method not working with parameter "files" for service.files().get(id) , it gives error invalid field.

So what should be used in setFields("") method to get all fields for service.files().get(id)??

Comment: try  using  setFields("*")

Comment: Well, if you check the Java example in the [documentaion](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#using_client_libraries), the `setFields` is use to get the `nextPageToken` and the `files(id, name)`. The [android quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/android) also use the `setFields` to `nextPageToken` and the `files(id, name)`

Comment: Right, but I am asking how to get all the fields for that single file. As, if I am not setting fields and only doing service.files().get(id) , I get only 4 by default fields which are name,kind,id and mimeType. There are more than 40 fields in total. So you mean to say I should set all of those 40 fields..??That is bizzare. There should be some single param that can be used in setFields("") to get all fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will have to set all the fields we want in the response file object in the method setFields() and those will be comma separated. It will do our work but I didn't find any single parameter that can do this work if we want all the fields.